# Mongo aggregation and basic queries

Tags: mongodb

I have a stock collection with multiple documents in the given below format in mongo db.

```
{
  Id: ‘RELI’
  Date: ‘2018-10-13’
  Price: 900
}
```

I want to write few queries:

1. Price series of a stock between date1 & date2.
2. Price series of a stock
3. Price of n(array of stock ids eg [Id1,Id2...] ) stock between d1 & d2.
4. Price of stock for last n year based on granularity (weekly & monthly). only need weekly and monthly data point.
   for past n months

I have written queries for first 2 issues

```
1. db.stocks.find({
  "id":"REL1",
  "price":{
     "$gte": ISODate(d1),
     "$lt": ISODate(d2)
   }
})


2.// Calculate the today’s date
   let d1 = new Date()
   // n is the number of months for which we are trying to fetch the 
   data
   Let d2 = d1.setMonth(d.getMonth() - n);

   db.stocks.find({
      "id":"REL1",
      "price":{
            "$gte": ISODate(d1),
            "$lt": ISODate(d2)
       }
    })
```

can you guys help me with 3rd and 4th or help me to optimise first two queries which I have written

Comment: Please try to explain your both the point widely.

Comment: 1. I want to fetch the price of n stocks between date1 and date2
2. price of stock for last n(for eg n=1) year. only want weekly and monthly data point
@AnthonyWinzlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the stock for last n year you can try below query

```
db.collection.find({
  "id": "REL1",
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      { "$year": {
        "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$Date" }
      }},
      2018
    ]
  }
})
```

And for the stock between `d1` and `d2`  your first query is perfect?

Comment: yes first query is correct, I'm stuck on 3rd and 4th

Comment: For the third one you can use above query

Comment: how to pass multiple ids for stocks? This is my first project in mongo, sorry for asking stupid questions

Comment: are you sure that query you wrote in answer will return weekly and monthly price for the particular stocks?
Don't we need to pass id?

Comment: Updated the answer.